# Where's passenger-side power window fuse

Tags: rav4, fuse-panel

The front passenger-side window of my RAV4 2015 stopped working. The glass won't go up or down. I can see there is a fuse box down on the left side of the steering wheel. I can see DOOR D, DOOR R/R, DOOR R/L fuses for driver's, rear right-hand, rear left-hand windows. Where is the fuse for front passenger door?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [wiring diagram](https://frankensteinmotorworks.com/2GRFE/diagrams/Toyota%20RAV4%20Electrical%20Wiring%20Diagrams%20%28EWD%29.pdf) the same fuse powers the driver and passenger side (the 30A fuse). There is also the 20A fuse at the top that is involved, but again, this is powering the drivers side window CPU.  Presumably the fuse you found as “DOOR D” is the 30A fuse.

Possibilities are now limited to -

- Drivers side switch module
- Passenger side switch
- Passenger side motor
- Wiring

I would start by unplugging the passenger side motor and putting power directly to it to see if the motor works.

After that, I would disconnect the passenger side switch and check it with a multimeter, or a battery and lamp.

It should be possible to check that the drivers switch is outputting the correct voltages on the green and brown wires. When the passenger controls are moved on the drivers side.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your answer. It turned out that the problem was due to door lock pressed.